# I want to install ubuntu-16.04-desktop-amd64 along with windows10 will it work and support 8gb RAM?

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

i am using windows10 32bit os (processor 64 bit)and i want to install ubuntu-16.04-desktop-amd64 alongside. I had squeezed my partition and  created some space for ubuntu. My bios mode is legacy. is it possible to install both alongside and will ubuntu support 8gb ram?

Answer (score 1):

"is it possible to install both alongside"

Yes

"and will ubuntu support 8gb ram?"

Yes